# Webkit CSS Transition fails on float property change

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-transitions

Hit an annoying bug in Webkit browsers, where CSS transitions aren't fired if you alter the float property. Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmarabeas/RxeWc/

Essentially, if you look to have a transition when an element's width changes, but also alter `float: left;` to `float: none;`, the transition simply doesn't fire. This causes further issues when you are intending on calling some JS on transition end:

```
$('#element').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend', function(){
    ...
}
```

I am applying a class changing the elements float property prior to the width alteration, and have tried both:

```
$(this).toggleClass('removeFloat widthChange');

//and

$(this).toggleClass('removeFloat');
$(this).toggleClass('widthChange');
```

I've hit this problem due to the need to use `white-space: nowrap;` in one particular instance of layout - which doesn't work with floated elements.

Comment: Interesting – not come across this before. Out of interest, why do you want to add and remove the float? In your example it doesn't seem to be different, though I appreciate that's likely a minimal test case.

Comment: @RichBradshaw This isn't demonstrated, but the first element on increased width pushes the other two elements right, overflowing outside of the parent div. Since you need `white-space: nowrap;` in order to preserve these elements on the same line, the float needs to be removed. I am using a grid system and would prefer that elements were floated and positioned normally, and altered only when needed. See the push example for the sort of functionality intended: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical SO session, spend an hour figuring out the root problem, search SO for a solution, find none, carefully construct question with example Fiddle while continuing to try every possible suggestion someone might come up with, and as a result solve your own problem. Thought it was odd ball enough to post anyway though.

Simply needed to examine the elements CSS after setting it, and prior to adjusting its width:

```
$(this).toggleClass('removeFloat');
$(this).css('float'); //or any other valid property
$(this).toggleClass('widthChange');
```

See this updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmarabeas/vrcaA/

---

**Edit:** Chrome looks to fixed the issue

Comment: Wow, this is what i call a strange bug. Really nice to share it!

Comment: actually, you have to call any valid CSS property on element e.g $(this).css('color');  http://jsfiddle.net/vrcaA/1/